# Rails multiple group_by to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash, group-by, associations

Here is the kind of models I want to sort.

I have one `User` who can have multiple `Post` and every of them has many `Statistic`.

To sum up this is what I have :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :statistics
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :statistics
end

class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What I want at the end is two tables (one cell = one day) :

1. One table that get all statistics from on user grouped by day, I've managed to get it
2. The second one is a little bit more complicated. I want the same thing but grouped by Post ID

For the first one, I've done that using :

```
# Group by day all statistics from one user
stats_by_date = current_user.statistics.group_by { |s| s.created_at.to_date }
# Transform the hash into an Array (one cell = one day)
@overall_statistics = stats_by_date.values
```

For the second one, I succeed to group my result for both Post ID and days but I don't know how to transform it into an exploitable Array, it means one table for each Post ID and in each table one cell for one day :

```
# Group statistics by posts
stats_by_post = current_user.statistics.group_by { |s| [s.created_at.to_date, s.post_id] }
```

Here is the Hash I get :

```
{
#[Thu, 07 May 2015, 2]=>[#<Statistic id: 68>, #<Statistic id: 69>, #<Statistic id: 74>],
#[Thu, 08 May 2015, 1]=>[#<Statistic id: 70>, #<Statistic id: 71>, #<Statistic id: 72>, #<Statistic id: 73>, #<Statistic id: 80>],
#[Thu, 08 May 2015, 2]=>[#<Statistic id: 70>, #<Statistic id: 71>, #<Statistic id: 72>, #<Statistic id: 73>, #<Statistic id: 80>],
# ...
}
```

How to create one table for each post?

What I want is this :

```
#--Table for : Post ID 2
#----First Cell (Thu, 07 May 2015)
#------[#<Statistic id: 68>, #<Statistic id: 69>, #<Statistic id: 74>]
#----Second cell (Thu, 08 May 2015)
#------[#<Statistic id: 70>, #<Statistic id: 71>, #<Statistic id: 72>, #<Statistic id: 73>, #<Statistic id: 80>]

#--Table for : Post ID 1
#----First Cell (Thu, 07 May 2015)
#------[#<Statistic id: 70>, #<Statistic id: 71>, #<Statistic id: 72>, #<Statistic id: 73>, #<Statistic id: 80>]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see two ways of constructing a nested hash as you described:

#### 1) Iterate twice, use `group_by` on two levels:

```
statistics_by_post = current_user.statistics.group_by(&:post_id)
@statistics_by_day_by_post = statistics_by_post.map do |p_id, stats|
  [p_id, stats.group_by{ |s| s.created_at.to_date }]
end.to_h
```

#### 2) Iterate once, group manually:

```
@statistics_by_day_by_post = {}
current_user.statistics.each do |s|
  post_id, day = s.post_id, s.created_at.to_date
  @statistics_by_day_by_post[post_id] ||= {}
  @statistics_by_day_by_post[post_id][day] ||= []
  @statistics_by_day_by_post[post_id][day] << s
end
```

HTH!